# Can't open synaptic package manager via command line

Tags: synaptic

When I try to open synaptic via the command line, I got this:

```
user@hostname ~ $ sudo synaptic
[sudo] password for user: 
No protocol specified

** (synaptic:4516): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

(synaptic:4516): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

What should I do?

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: root does not have permission to open an X session on your display.

Answer (score 2):

Your shell environment is for some reason missing the `DISPLAY` variable. A quick workaround would be the following call:

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 sudo synaptic
```

A more advanced and secure variant, for the reasons described below by *sudodus*, would be to use a graphical sudo frontend:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0; gksudo synaptic
```

However, this will be of no use if you don't have an X server running, e. g. because you're running a headless system or you're in runlevel 1. You'll need to use `apt-get` instead of some graphical frontend then.

Comment: You should never use plain `sudo` with graphical user interface programs. Instead you should use the command `sudo -H gui-program-name` . This prevents the root user from hijacking files in your user-ID's home directory. An alternative is to install the package `gksu`and use `gksudo gui-program-name`